# How do I create a regular expression to replace a known string while keeping optional parameters intact?

Tags: java, regex

I've been trying out now for a while, but don't get it right:
In Java, I am trying to create a regular expression to match and replace a (to me known) string out of a string while keeping optional parameters intact.

Example inputs:

```
{067e6162-3b6f-4ae2-a171-2470b63dff00}
{067e6162-3b6f-4ae2-a171-2470b63dff00,number}
{067e6162-3b6f-4ae2-a171-2470b63dff00,number,integer}
{067e6162-3b6f-4ae2-a171-2470b63dff00,choice,1#one more item|1<another {067e6162-3b6f-4ae2-a171-2470b63dff00,number,integer} items}
```

(Note that the last example contains a nested reference to the same input string).
The format is always enclosing the to-be-replaced string in curly brackets `{...}` but with an optional list of comma-separated parameter(s).

I want to replace the input string with a number, e.g. for above input strings the result should be:

```
{2}
{2,number}
{2,number,integer}
{2,choice,1#one more item|1<another {2,number,integer} items}
```

Ideally, I'd like to have a regex that is flexible enough to handle (almost) any string as pattern to be replaced, so not just UUID kind of strings as above but also something like this:

```
A test string with {the_known_input_value_to_be_replaced,number,integer} not replacing the_known_input_value_to_be_replaced if its not in curly brackets of course.
```

which should end up as e.g.:

```
A test string with {3,number,integer} not replacing the_known_input_value_to_be_replaced if its not in curly brackets of course.
```

Note that the substitution should only take place if the input string is in curly brackets.
In Java I will be able to construct the pattern at runtime, taking the to-be-replaced string into account verbosely.

I tried e.g. `\{(067e6162-3b6f-4ae2-a171-2470b63dff00)(,?.*)\}` (not java escaped yet) and more generic approaches like `\{(+?)(,?.*)\}` , but they all don't do it right.

Any advice from regex ninjas highly appreciated :)

Comment: Does it always occur right after `{`? Then, you can just use `.replace("{" + myOLDkeyword, "{" + myNEWkeyword);`.

Comment: Yes it does.. good point! I'll give that a shot and will update here later! Thanks @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: if string after `{` is always known string, here is not needed regex. @WiktorStribiżew gave a good solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you the known old string always occurs right after `{` you can just use

```
String result = old_text.replace("{" + my_old_keyword, "{" + my_new_keyword);
```

If you really have multiple known strings inside curly brackets (and there are no escaped curly brackets to take care of), you can use the following code:

```
String input = "067e6162-3b6f-4ae2-a171-2470b63dff00 is outside {067e6162-3b6f-4ae2-a171-2470b63dff00,choice,067e6162-3b6f-4ae2-a171-2470b63dff00,1#one more item|1<another {067e6162-3b6f-4ae2-a171-2470b63dff00,number,067e6162-3b6f-4ae2-a171-2470b63dff00,integer} items} 067e6162-3b6f-4ae2-a171-2470b63dff00 is outside ";
String old_key = "067e6162-3b6f-4ae2-a171-2470b63dff00";
String new_key = "NEW_KEY";
List<String> chunks = replaceInBalancedSubstrings(input, '{', '}', old_key, new_key);
System.out.println(String.join("", chunks));
```

Result: `067e6162-3b6f-4ae2-a171-2470b63dff00 is outside {{NEW_KEY,choice,NEW_KEY,1#one more item|1<another {NEW_KEY,number,NEW_KEY,integer} items} 067e6162-3b6f-4ae2-a171-2470b63dff00 is outside`

The `replaceInBalancedSubstrings`    method will look like:

```
public static List<String> replaceInBalancedSubstrings(String s, Character markStart, Character markEnd, String old_key, String new_key) {
    List<String> subTreeList = new ArrayList<String>();
    int level = 0;
    int prevStart = 0;
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    int lastOpenBracket = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        char c = s.charAt(i);
        if (level == 0) {
            sb.append(c);
        }
        if (c == markStart) {
            level++;
            if (level == 1) {
                lastOpenBracket = i;
                if (sb.length() > 0) {
                    subTreeList.add(sb.toString());
                    sb.delete(0, sb.length());
                }
            }
        }
        else if (c == markEnd) {
            if (level == 1) {
                subTreeList.add(s.substring(lastOpenBracket, i+1).replace(old_key, new_key)); // String replacement here
            }
            level--;
        }
    }
    if (sb.length() > 0) {
        subTreeList.add(sb.toString());
    }
    return subTreeList;
}
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/CmUQGB)

This code will deal with replacements only inside substrings inside balanced (nested) curly braces.

Comment: Thanks @Wiktor! (One small unrelated thing: I would probably end up using `StringBuilder` instead of `StringBuffer`)

Comment: I read about the difference, but I have always used `StringBuffer` in the "replacement callbacks", and it always worked well. Anyway, glad to help.